# PyMel EulerAngles changes after identity matrix multiplication

Tags: matrix, scripting, maya, pymel

I'am using PyMel and I am trying to get the same rotation back from a matrix after I have multiplied the rotation matrix with two other matricies.
changeOfBasisMInv and changeOfBasisM are both identity matricies that I multiply with currentRotationM.

At print correct rotation I get:[-4.31299357788, 2.67204629907, -0.515487334308]

At isolated rotation I get: [-1.17140092429, 0.469546354516, 2.62610531928]

The matricies currentRotationM and isolatedRotationM are the same, so why can't I use getRotation() and get the same euler angles after multiplication?
All my matricies are TransformationMatricies

```
print ("Correct Rotation")
print(type(currentRotationM.getRotation()))
isolatedRotationM = changeOfBasisMInv * changeOfBasisM*currentRotationM
print ("Isolated Rotation")
print(isolatedRotationM.getRotation())
```

Comment: You should try to make a complete example which runs directly in maya.e.g. you do not show how you construct the changeOfBasisM and changeOfBasisMInv. If your other matrices are identity matrices, you should get the same result, at least that's what I get.

Comment: Have you checked to see if the results are visually identical?  The rotations are being calculated from the matrices, and there are multiple valid eulerizations of  a given matrix.

Comment: The before and after matricies have the same values and the rotation result is wrong. The values i wrote are my euler values in world space.

Comment: Yes but what rotation order are you using?

Comment: I have [-4.31299357788, 2.67204629907, -0.515487334308] before multiplication and [-1.17140092429, 0.469546354516, 2.62610531928] after multiplication with identity matricies, which should still be [-4.31299357788, 2.67204629907, -0.515487334308]